# What is the Terraform resource for this AWS console item?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am looking to add notifications to a build pipeline I am deploying in AWS via Terraform. I cannot seem to locate the resource which creates the status notifications in CodeBuild. Can someone let me know which resource this is?

[image: Screenshot of the AWS CodeBuild administrative console, with an arrow annotation pointing at the "Notify" button associated with a particular project.]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Tip for the future : try to embed pictures directly into question as it is easier for readers and there is less risk that picture would be deleted from CDN.

Comment: If you update your question to have specific details of the notification I can update my answer below with an example code block.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve not mentioned what sort of notification you are looking to create, so I won’t be able to provide some sample code, however, as per the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html), you can detect state changes jn CodePipeline using Cloudwatch events.

You can find the Terraform reference for CloudWatch Event Rules [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_event_rule.html), and you can follow the docs to create a resource that monitors CodePipeline for state changes using CloudWatch Events Rules.